# Convert .MDF to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

How do I convert a database that is in .MDF and .LDF to MySQL?

I have tried various ways. Is there an easy solution?

Comment: What ways have you tried?  Also, have you done any research?  Here's a link to a paper that might help (warning: you have to log in to get to it):  http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-migrating-from-sql-server-to-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/

*The MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard is designed to save DBA and developer time by providing visual, point and click ease of use around all phases of configuring and managing a complex migration process:
Improved! Database migrations - enables migrations from Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Sybase ASE, Sybase SQL Anywhere, SQLite, and more.*